# Опросник древо PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Вообщем ребят нужен ваш совет или же помощь, есть алгоритм из другой области.
Нужно на его основе создать (???) Я признаться даже не знаю как это называется
PHP опросник-древо
Вообщем смысл такой, Задается вопрос - предоставляется выбор одного из двух вариантов, либо необходимость введение данных вручную, и соответственное в конце выдается ответ.
Условно на примере картинки "На измерительной панели напряжение путевого реле?"---> "Uрел > Uпит !"--> "Cостояние путевого реле?"--->"Реле под током!".На экране высвечивается результат : Неисправен повторитель путевого реле[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И в чем проблема то? Какой совет нужен? За вас это писать вряд ли кто будет...

Comment: И?.. У вопросов есть ответы...каждый ответ ссылается на другой вопрос..

Comment: Какой командой это соображать и прикручивать ли к этому базу?Новичок, а посему не знаю.

Comment: @SamuraiSidzygohara, Вам лучше знать прикручивать ли вам это к базе или нет - это же Ваша задача.

Comment: @SamuraiSidzygohara, ваш вопрос слишком общий... люди не понимают на что именно им нужно отвечать. Прочитайте справку: [Как задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) . После чего уточните Ваш вопрос, хотя у меня складывается впечатление что Вам его стоит разбить на несколько других вопросов... В таком виде на него никто не ответит, потому что вопрос слишком общий, а поставленную на Вас задачу за Вас тут никто решать не будет.

Comment: В чем проблема?..Вы не понимаете как связи между двумя объектами реализовать?

Comment: почитайте про [виды связей в реляционной бд](https://habr.com/ru/post/193380/), а ещё лучше прочитайте все руководство по проектированию реляционных баз данных... после этого посмотрите как хранить деревья в реляционной базе данных

Comment: Автор, есть какие-то сдвиги в этом вопросе?

Comment: @РустамГимранов на данный момент абсолютно никаких...
Сделал все на htmlе (куча страниц), все работает, но пока как сообразить что бы это было в базе никак не могу.

Answer (score 0):

Вот не тривиальный пример. Если писать тест то все вопросы и ответы должны быть в mysql соответственно, с учётом записи и логирования студентов и их ответов ну итд.

```
<html>
<body>
    <p>Если на измерительной панели измерить напряж путевого реле</p>
<div>
<form action="rooti.php" method="post">
<p><select name="mysel" >
  <option>Напряжение меньше</option>
  <option>Напряжение больше</option>
  <option>Незнаю</option>
  <option>Свой вариант</option>
</select></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Отправить" /></p>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<?php

$otvet=$_POST["mysel"];


if($otvet=='Напряжение меньше'){

    echo "Напряжение на высокой стороне";
}else{
    echo "Проверить состояние путевого реле";
}


?>
```

Comment: я не думаю что автор не знает как реализовать форму... он этого не спрашивал и это не является ответом на данный вопрос, насколько я это понимаю.

Comment: Ему дал простейший пример, если надо будет и чекбоксы прикручивать и всё остальное делать, он походу новичёк, это была ему подсказка

Comment: пример чего?.. я не видел, чтобы автор говорил - я не знаю как реализовать форму... он скорее всего не понимает как организовать данную структуру в базе данных

Comment: Ну это уже история умалчивает

Comment: если Вы не понимаете что имеет в виду автор(причем от слова совсем), то лучше не тратить своё время на ответ.. Вы с потратите своё время, а ещё и минусов нахватаете.

Comment: лучше постараться выяснить у автора, что он имел в виду